# Content is disappearing from my wordpress site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I'm a having a pretty weird issue going on with a Wordpress site. The URL is www.johnmichaelmarketing.com

The content from some pages is progressively disappearing and the site members can't even log into their accounts. There was a YouTube video in the home page and now it's not there.

You can see the pages content in the editor section but once it goes live it's like a ghost page. It all was working fine and all of the sudden it all started to fall apart. I haven't messed up with .php files or anything because it's not a theme I created and plus, it was working fine; I have no reason to do it.

Comment: This is not really a coding question. It's more a job for a freelancer or software company to do some fixes at your website. Please also do not use smileys in your posts. At SO we are dead serious about your problems and we never laugh.

Comment: I never understood why coders are like that. I'm sorry you don't laugh, you should try it sometime :))))) you're SO dead serious about my problems that you couldn't even solve it :D thanks for giving it a try I guess(?) have a nice week :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make any updates? Could be version issues with your hosts. You could restore a backup of working site. 101 usually works